# Only one head phone (Right) working on my andrioid razor

Tags: headphone-jack

Has anyone had this issue on their android where only one headphone is playing music. I use Pandora and I already did a factory reset and still nothing. Anyone have any other ideas?>

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried the headphone on other device (e.g. PC)? If it also occurs there, then the problem is on the headphone (e.g. the cable is cut internally). Otherwise, we still can't pin-point the cause without additional info.

Answer (score 1):

Try another headphone ? It's very likely the one you have its defective